# What's the difference between the JSON and tmTheme theme files on Microsoft VS Code?

Tags: json, themes, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

First I'm trying to combine the High Contrast theme with the Monokai. I like the way the UI looks with High Contrast but the text color is the default Dark theme from Visual Studio and I want to change this to Monokai.

I went looking for the theme files under "...\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions.."

High Contrast - "..\theme-defaults\themes\hc_black.json"

Monokai - "..\theme-monokai\themes\Monokai.tmTheme"

Upon inspection the attributes on both files seem different so I can't map them 1 to 1. Before I dabble on the code and start a trial and error approach what is the main difference between these files on the context of VS Code? And is there a way to convert from one to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I continued to fiddle around in the files and I finally got it, for others in the same situation here's how you solve this.

The JSON files I aluded to on my question are actually UI Themes and the tmTheme files are color schemes for syntax highlight.

Each theme has a package.json and on this file there is an attribute called "uiTheme" that you can change.

Currently the themes that I know off are the following:

- vs
- vs-dark
- hc-black (the one I wanted)

For more information on this check out the Common Questions at the end of this page:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/themes